write csv files or delta tables from databricks to MS access database using databricks notebook
I want to write csv files / delta tables to MS Access database from Databricks. accdb file is stored in dbfs. I tried to use library ucanaccess but i can only read from access database . writing is not possible. pyodbc also does not work on Databricks because access drivers are not there on cluster. if i install odbc drivers( ms access drivers) on my laptop, I can read and write access database using python in vs code on my laptop. same setup does not work on Databricks. has anyone implement such requirement ?

did you try with JDBC https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

yes. i can read from ms access db using ucanaccess in databricks. but writing to accdb is not possible using ucanacess.
